# inline assembly - useless intermediate copy instructions

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly, cpu-registers, mov

I'm trying to write a scheduler to run what we call "fibers".
Unfortunately, I'm not really used to writing inline assembly.

```
typedef struct {
    //fiber's stack
    long rsp;
    long rbp;

    //next fiber in ready list
    struct fiber *next;

} fiber;

//currently executing fiber
fiber *fib;
```

So the very first task is - obviously - creating a fiber for the `main` function so it can be suspended.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    //create fiber for main function
    fib = malloc(sizeof(*fib));
    __asm__(
        "movq %%rsp, %0;"
        "movq %%rbp, %1;"
         : "=r"(fib->rsp),"=r"(fib->rbp)
         );

    //jump to actual main and execute
    __asm__(...);

}
```

This gets compiled to

```
    movl    $24, %edi   #,
    call    malloc  #
#APP
# 27 "scheduler.c" 1
    movq %rsp, %rcx;movq %rbp, %rdx;    # tmp92, tmp93
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
    movq    %rax, fib(%rip) # tmp91, fib
    movq    %rcx, (%rax)    # tmp92, MEM[(struct fiber *)_3].rsp
    movq    %rdx, 8(%rax)   # tmp93, MEM[(struct fiber *)_3].rbp
```

Why does this compile `mov`s into temporary registers? Can I somehow get rid of them?

The first version of this question had asm output from `gcc -O0`, with even more instructions and temporaries.

Turning on optimisations does not get rid of them.

Comment: Did  you enable optimizations?

Comment: @Jester I hadn't at first, but turning them on does not get rid of the temporaries (see edit above).

Comment: C does not support _methods_

Comment: You can write the whole function in assembly, which you can compile with NASM or GNU assembler, and finally link it with the rest of the application. Then call the ASM function from the C code.

Comment: Why is `rbp` special for your fibers?  Surely you need to save/restore all registers.  `rsp` is the only one that's special: you can use it to find a fiber's stack (where you saved the other registers, I assume).

Comment: Also, you might want to use `uintptr_t` or even `void*` instead of `long`.  If you care about portability, keep in mind that the x32 ABI uses 32bit pointers, and `long` is 32bit, but the registers are still 64bit.  You only need to save 32bit `esp`, but you need to save all 64 bits of `rbp` since it could be holding a 64bit temporary.  (`-fomit-frame-pointer` is the default.)  Presumably you `push`/`pop` to save regs, so you're fine.

Comment: @PeterCordes I was under the impression that a stack frame is given by a base pointer rbp, that points to the beginning of the frame, and a stack pointer rsp, that keeps track of the next available location. I don't immediately see how the rsp is sufficient?

Comment: @User1291: restore `rsp`, pop all the other regs one at a time, including `rbp`.  Boom, you're back.  If the function you resumed was using `rbp` as a frame pointer, then it still is.  You've resumed from the saved context, restoring *all* state except for the memory where you stored registers.  (Remember that the SystemV AMD64 ABI uses a 128B red-zone, so before pushing registers, you should `add $-128, %rsp` so you save them below the current function's red-zone.  After popping the state back into regs, `sub $-128, %rsp`.  (-128 fits in an `imm8`, but +128 doesn't, hence the double-negative)

Comment: If you only save/restore from inside an `__attribute__((noinline))` function (which you could write directly in asm, not inline-asm), you only need to save/restore the call-preserved registers, which doesn't include any of the vector registers in the System V ABI.  It also means you don't have to worry about the red-zone.  Like `setjmp` / `longjmp`, callers of the function expect clobbering of some of the registers, and use of memory below the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> turning them on does not get rid of the temporaries

It did get rid of some extra loads and stores. The `fib` is of course still there in memory since you declared that as a global variable. The `rax` is the return value from the `malloc` that must be assigned to the `fib` in memory. The other two lines write into your `fib` members which are also required.

Since you specified register outputs the asm block can't write directly into memory. That's easy to fix with a memory constraint though:

```
__asm__(
    "movq %%rsp, %0;"
    "movq %%rbp, %1;"
     : "=m"(fib->rsp),"=m"(fib->rbp)
     );
```

This will generate:

```
    call    malloc
    movq    %rax, fib(%rip)
    movq    %rsp, (%rax)
    movq    %rbp, 8(%rax)
```

Comment: You should probably use `"=rm"` to give the compiler the option.  It won't matter in this case, but if you write code that looks at those values, the compiler can keep them in regs instead of doing a store->load.  (Although ideally there'd be a way to make a C variable refer to the value of `rbp` without using any instructions.)  Clang sometimes makes poor choices if given multi-option constraints, so check the code for that case.  (Actually, I don't remember the details of when I saw clang do poorly with GNU C `asm` statements, but it can happen.)